# Javascript + Twitter-boostrap - Why is autoclose not working on this javascript?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

```js
    $('#datepicker0').datepicker({
      autoclose: true,
      format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div >
  <div >
    <label for="datepicker0">Execution Date:</label>
  </div>
  <div >
    <input class="form-control date-picker" id="datepicker0" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$().ready(function () {
    $('#datepicker0').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        language: "pt-BR",
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
    });
});
```

On a page I got this datepicker javascript function. But when selecting a date, the autoclose isn't working. What's wrong here?

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't have a native date picker, what library are you using?

Comment: Looks like your using https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html? I dont see a reason for this not to work

Comment: well, funny thing is that `format` works just fine...

Comment: Post a demo and I can see whats up

Comment: Instead of `$()` I think this must be `$(document)`?

Comment: thanks for your input, @aldrin27, did not work, though.